# How to convert a NotesDocument to MIME

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Why does the following function always return `Nothing`?

```vb
Function GetMimeEntity(Doc As NotesDocument) As NotesMimeEntity
    Set GetMimeEntity = Doc.GetMIMEEntity

    If GetMimeEntity Is Nothing Then
        Doc.ConvertToMIME 2
        Set GetMimeEntity = Doc.GetMIMEEntity
    End If
End Function
```

`Doc` is an email.

Comment: Did you try doc.ConvertToMIME(2, 0) ?

Comment: I guess [this bug](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/LO47200) did not get solved in the next release, or you are using Notes 8.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you setting `session.convertMIME = false` before running this? Otherwise the NotesSession will convert any MIME content to CD records.

Comment: Thanks. Your simple answer with this background info helped me better understand what's going on https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/plan_dominomailfiles_c.html